# How to speed up a netbook running Windows

Tags: windows-7

I have a netbook running Windows 7 Starter edition 32 bits, CPU Intel Atom N270 1.60 GHz, RAM 1 GB, HD 150 GB (it's a HP Mini 110).

How can make it run a little faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how the Windows 7 Starter edition works, I think there are some restriction on how much you can tweak it but you can try [delaying some of the services](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/start-your-computer-more-quickly-by-delaying-the-startup-of-a-service-in-vista/) at startup or [disabling the search service](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10246/how-to-disable-search-in-windows-7/) (indexing).

Other than that, use light applications and if you can add another GB of ram.